# The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed

Tags: windows

I have had this win 7 PC for a few years now. It comes from an office that had a network, and the PC was on the domain.  The domain is long gone, but the PC is always looking for the domain. when I try to change passwords or add users, I get his error message:

"The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

I have read every post there is on this issue, but they all have access to the domain server. My situation is unique in that there is no server. I am able to use the PC by logging in using the name of the domain\user, and then the password, and can use the PC normally, except I am a remote user with admin auth.

i had the same issue with another PC and just wiped the HD and started from scratch. I would sure like to avoid that now.

I am thinking it is some sort of registry issue, some key i can change, something to tell the PC to stop looking for the server, it doesnt exist anymore, so i can get control of the PC locally.

---

Comment: Put the answer in an answer, not the question.

Comment: See solution posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: SOLUTION

For anybody else with the issue, here is the solution that worked for me (WIN 7):

To remove your PC from the domain

a) First make sure you are logged-on as the local or domain administrator

b) Click START, CONTROL PANEL

c) Once in control panel, double click the ADMINISTRATIVE TOOLS folder

d) Once in the administrative tools folder, double click the COMPUTER MANAGEMENT icon

e) A window will appear and you will have a list of items on the left. Click the LOCAL USERS AND GROUPS icon on the left.

f) Double click the USERS folder on the right

g) RIGHT click and choose NEW USER

h) Enter a username you desire, for this example I will use stravs, you can enter a full name and a description if you want but it is not necessary. Enter a password and confirm the password. UNCHECK "User much change password at logon" and CHECK "Password never expires"

i) Click CREATE

j) On the left side of the screen, click the GROUPS folder

k) On the right side of the screen, double click ADMINISTRATORS

i) You will see a list of user accounts that are currently local administrators of this laptop. Click the ADD button near the bottom.

j) A window will appear, type in the username you just created (ex: stravs) and click OK

k) Click OK to close the current window (Administrators Properties), click the RED X to close the current window (Computer Management)

l) You should be back in the administrative tools folder, go back one level to take you back to the CONTROL PANEL

m) Once in control panel, double click the SYSTEM icon

n) A window will appear with multiple tabs. Click the COMPUTER NAME tab

o) Here you will see the full computer name and the domain it is current attached to. Near the bottom of the window click the CHANGE button

p) Another window will appear listing the computer name and below that you will see Domain is selected and the domain name is shown. Leave the computer name alone for now. Click the WORKGROUP radio button and type anything in the box below it (this will become the name of the workgroup your PC will belong to and it doesn't matter what you type)

q) Click OK - A window will appear asking for a USERNAME and PASSWORD, enter the domain username and password used to login in locally

r) You will then get another window that says something to the effect of "Welcome to the ..... workgroup" Click OK

s) You must RESTART your PC for these changes to take effect.

t) Once your PC restarts, you should be able to login without that annoying domain issue.